# Как правильно расписать нахождение центра окружности на си в данной задаче?

Tags: c, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

*Задан размер массива действительных чисел и значения его элементов. Считая, что пары элементов представляют собой координаты точек на плоскости, проверить, могут ли все данные точки лежать на одной окружности и, если да, найти ее радиус.*

В программе количество точек и координаты должен вводить пользователь

Рекомендация от препода: Размер массива определяется исходя из условия индивидуального задания. В тех случаях, когда максимальный размер исходного массива не оговорен, полагать, что он равен 20.`введите сюда код`

вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of points: ");
    while ((scanf("%d", &n) != 1) || (n <= 0)) {
        printf("Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer: ");
        while (getchar() != '\n'); 
    }

    double x[n];
    double y[n];

    printf("Enter the coordinates of the points:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
        printf("Point %d: ", (i/2) + 1);
        while (scanf("%lf %lf", &points[i], &points[i + 1]) != 2) {
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter an integer: ");
            while (getchar() != '\n'); 
        }
    }
    
    double sum_x = 0, sum_y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i += 2) {
        sum_x += points[i];
        sum_y += points[i+1];
    }
    double center_x = sum_x / n;
    double center_y = sum_y / n;

    double radius = 0;
    int S = 1;
    double distances[n]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i += 2) {
        distances[i / 2] = sqrt(pow(points[i] - center_x, 2) + pow(points[i + 1] - center_y, 2));
        if (i == 0) {
            radius = distances[0];
        } else {
            if (fabs(distances[i / 2] - radius) > 0) {
                S = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (S) {
        printf("All points lie on the same circle.\n");
        printf("Radius: %.2f\n", radius);
    } else {
        printf("The points do not lie on the same circle.\n");
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

не понимаю как правильно расписать нахождение центра окружности, также преподаватель указал на то что неправильно объявлен массив, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [помогите решить задачу на Си](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555925/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1%d0%b8)

Comment: Намек: окружность определяется тремя точками...

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от закрытого несколько дней назад такого же вопроса?

Answer (score 2):

**Нахождение центра окружности и её радиуса по 3 точкам.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даны 3 точки: A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2) и C(x3,y3);

Пусть точка D(x0,y0) - центр окружности, а точки M(xm,ym) и N(xn,yn) - середины хорд AB и BC.

1. В соответствие с теоремой о среднем перпендикуляре к хорде, линии DM и DN будут перпендикулярами.
2. Запишем уравннение прямой AB: (x-x1) / (x2-x1) = (y-y1) / (y2-y1)
3. Переходим от канонического уравнения прямой к уравнению с угловым коэффициентом (y = m_ab * x + b_ab): m_ab = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1); b_ab = y1 - x1(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
4. Соответственно, угловой коэффициент перпендикуляра DM к прямой AB будет равен: _m_ab = -1/m_ab = (x1-x2) / (y2-y1)
5. Так же вычислим m_bc = (y3-y2) / (x3-x2) и _m_bc = (x2-x3) / (y3-y2)
6. Запишем m_dm = (ym-y0) / (xm-x0); m_dn = (yn-y0) / (xn-x0)
7. Составим систему { _m_ab = m_dm; _m_bc = m_dn }
8. Получим: { y0 = (x1-x2)/(y2-y1) * x0 + ym - xm * (x1-x2)/(y2-y1); y0 = (x2-x3)/(y3-y2) * x0 + yn - xn * (x2-x3)/(y3-y2) }
9. Пусть { y0 = am * x0 + dm; y0 = an * x0 + dn }
10. Получим: x0 = (dn - dm) / (am - an); А y0 = am * x0 + dm, соответсвенно.
11. Радиус равен дистанции между D и A; r = sqrt((x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void swap(double* a, double* b) {
    double temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

bool has(double* beg, double* end, double x, double y) {
    for(double* it = beg; it < end; it += 2)
        if(*it == x && *(it + 1) == y)
            return true;
    return false;
}

double* scan(int* n) {
    double x, y;
    double *arr, *ptr;

    printf("Enter the number of points: ");
    scanf("%d", n);

    while(*n < 3) {
        printf("Wrong!!! Input must be greater or equal to 3!\nEnter the number of points: ");
        scanf("%d", n);
    }

    arr = (double*) malloc((*n << 1) * sizeof(double));
    ptr = arr;

    printf("Enter the coordinates of the points:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < *n; ++i, ptr += 2) {
        // Считываем x и y
        printf("Point %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf %lf", &x, &y);

        // Проверка была ли точка уже введена
        if(has(arr, ptr + 1, x, y)) {
            printf("Point already exists! Input another one!\n");
            ptr -= 2;
            --i;
            continue;
        }

        // Записываем точку в массива
        *ptr = x;
        *(ptr + 1) = y;
    }
    *n = *n << 1;
    return arr;
}

// Проблема состоит в том, что иногда y2-y1 = 0 или y3-y2 = 0
// что приводит к x0 = NaN, y0 = NaN и r = NaN
// функция prep проходится по массиву и записывает в первые 6 ячеек
// массива значения которые не вызовут ошибок
void prep(double* arr, int n) {
    for(int i = 2; i < 6; i += 2) {
        if(arr[i - 1] != arr[i + 1]) { continue; }

        for(int j = 0; j < n; j += 2) {
            if(j == i || arr[i - 1] == arr[j + 1]) { continue; }
            
            (void) swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
            (void) swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[j + 1]);
            i = 2;
        }
    }
}

// По теореме Пифагора расстояние между двумя точками:
// dist = sqrt((xn - x0)^2 + (yn - y0)^2)
double dist(double x0, double y0, double xn, double yn) {
    // Вычисляем (xn - x0)^2
    xn -= x0; xn *= xn;
    // Вычисляем (yn - y0)^2
    yn -= y0; yn *= yn;
    return sqrt(xn + yn);
}

void calc(double* arr, double* radius, double* x0, double* y0) {
    double xm = (arr[0] + arr[2]) / 2;
    double ym = (arr[1] + arr[3]) / 2;
    double am = (arr[0] - arr[2]) / (arr[3] - arr[1]);
    double dm = ym - xm * am;

    double xn = (arr[2] + arr[4]) / 2;
    double yn = (arr[3] + arr[5]) / 2;
    double an = (arr[2] - arr[4]) / (arr[5] - arr[3]);
    double dn = yn - xn * an;

    *x0 = (dn - dm) / (am - an);
    *y0 = am * (*x0) + dm;
    *radius = dist(*x0, *y0, arr[0], arr[1]);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    double *arr;
    double new_r, r, x0, y0;

    arr = scan(&n);
    (void) prep(arr, n);
    (void) calc(arr, &r, &x0, &y0);

    new_r = r;
    for(int i = 6; i < n; i += 2) {
        // Находим дистанцию от каждой новой точки до предполагаемого центра
        new_r = dist(x0, y0, arr[i], arr[i + 1]);

        // Если найденная дистанция не равна радиусу окружности
        // значит  данная точка не лежит на данной окружности
        // выходим из цикла
        if(new_r != r) { break; }
    }

    if(new_r == r) {
        printf("All points are on the same circle!\n");
        printf("Radius: %lf; Center: (%lf, %lf)\n", r, x0, y0);
    }
    else { printf("Not all points are on the same circle!\n"); }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, это `void scan(int& n, double*& arr)` — не C.

Comment: Вы бы все же поподробнее описали, что делает функция calc (как ей можно воспользоваться для определения окружности в аналогичных задачах) и как функция dist взаимодействует с результатом ее работы для этой задачи

Comment: @avp Добавил описание

Answer (score 1):

#### Решение

Вот так можно найти центр окружности по трём точкам:

```
...
    double a, b, c, d;
    buildCircle3(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, &a, &b, &c, &d);
    if (c != 0) {
        double r = sqrt(a * a + b * b - 4 * c * d) / (2 * c);
        double x = -a / (2 * c);
        double y = -b / (2 * c);
    }
...

void buildCircle3(
    double x1, double y1,
    double x2, double y2,
    double x3, double y3,
    double *a, double *b, double *c, double *d
) {
    const double r1 = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1;
    const double r2 = x2 * x2 + y2 * y2;
    const double r3 = x3 * x3 + y3 * y3;

    const double x2y3 = x2 * y3 - x3 * y2;
    const double x3y1 = x3 * y1 - x1 * y3;
    const double x1y2 = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1;

    *a = r1 * (y3 - y2) + r2 * (y1 - y3) + r3 * (y2 - y1);
    *b = r1 * (x2 - x3) + r2 * (x3 - x1) + r3 * (x1 - x2);

    *c =        x2y3 +      x3y1 +      x1y2 ;
    *d = -(r1 * x2y3 + r2 * x3y1 + r3 * x1y2);
}
```

#### Объяснение

Я буду изображать определители таблицами. Извините.

Утверждение: если точки *(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>)*, *(x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>)*, *(x<sub>3</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>)* не лежат на одной прямой, то определитель ниже равен нулю тогда и только тогда, когда точка *(x, y)* лежит на окружности проходящей через *(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>)*, *(x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>)*, *(x<sub>3</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>)*.

| *x* | *y* | *x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub>* | *y<sub>1</sub>* | *x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub>* | *y<sub>2</sub>* | *x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub>* | *y<sub>3</sub>* | *x<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |

Убедится в этом не сложно. Правый столбец из единиц можно использовать чтобы прибавлять одну и ту же константу ко всем иксам. Значение определителя не поменяется. В свою очередь столбец из иксов можно прибавлять к столбцу из квадратов. Следите за руками. Удвоенный столбец иксов добавляется к столбцу квадратов:

| *x* | *y* | *x<sup>2</sup> + 2x + y<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub>* | *y<sub>1</sub>* | *x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2x<sub>1</sub> + y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub>* | *y<sub>2</sub>* | *x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2x<sub>2</sub> + y<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub>* | *y<sub>3</sub>* | *x<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2x<sub>3</sub> + y<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |

Cтолбец единиц добавляется к столбцу иксов и к столбцу квадратов:

| *x + 1* | *y* | *x<sup>2</sup> + 2x + 1 + y<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub> + 1* | *y<sub>1</sub>* | *x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2x<sub>1</sub> + 1 + y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub> + 1* | *y<sub>2</sub>* | *x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2x<sub>2</sub> + 1 + y<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub> + 1* | *y<sub>3</sub>* | *x<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2x<sub>3</sub> + 1 + y<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |

Соберем квадраты в скобки:

| *x + 1* | *y* | *(x + 1)<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub> + 1* | *y<sub>1</sub>* | *(x<sub>1</sub> + 1)<sup>2</sup> + y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub> + 1* | *y<sub>2</sub>* | *(x<sub>2</sub> + 1)<sup>2</sup> + y<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub> + 1* | *y<sub>3</sub>* | *(x<sub>3</sub> + 1)<sup>2</sup> + y<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>* | *1* |

Получилось, что все иксы в определителе увеличились на единицу, а его значение не изменилось. То есть, определитель сохраняет значение при трансляции по *x* на единицу. На самом деле определитель сохраняет значение при любой трансляции по *x* и по *y*.

Обозначим *(x<sub>c</sub>, y<sub>c</sub>)* - центр окружности проходящей через *(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>)*, *(x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>)*, *(x<sub>3</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>)*. Выполним трансляцию:

| *x - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y - y<sub>c</sub>* | *(x - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *(x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *(x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *(x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |

Нижние три значения в столбце квадратов - квадрат радиуса окружности. Обозначим *r<sup>2</sup> = (x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = (x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup>*:

| *x - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y - y<sub>c</sub>* | *(x - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *r<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *r<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *r<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |

С помощью столбца единиц вычтем *r<sup>2</sup>* из столбца квадратов:

| *x - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y - y<sub>c</sub>* | *(x - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> - r<sup>2</sup>* | *1* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *0* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *0* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *0* | *1* |

Разложим определитель по верхней строке. Миноры при *x - x<sub>c</sub>* , *y - y<sub>c</sub>* и *1* равны нулю - в каждом есть столбец из нулей. Единственное не нулевое слагаемое это *((x - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> - r<sup>2</sup>)* умноженный на минор:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>c</sub>* | *y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>c</sub>* | *1* |

Убираем из него трансляцию на *(-x<sub>c</sub>, -y<sub>c</sub>)*:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *x<sub>1</sub>* | *y<sub>1</sub>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>2</sub>* | *y<sub>2</sub>* | *1* |
| *x<sub>3</sub>* | *y<sub>3</sub>* | *1* |

Этот минор может быть равен нулю только если *x<sub>1</sub>*, *x<sub>2</sub>*, *x<sub>3</sub>* на одной прямой - это и есть уравнение прямой. Но у нас точки на окружности, не на прямой. Значит нулём должен стать другой множитель: *((x - x<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - y<sub>c</sub>)<sup>2</sup> - r<sup>2</sup>) = 0*. А он может стать нулём только если точка *(x, y)* находится на расстоянии *r* от центра окружности *(x<sub>c</sub>, y<sub>c</sub>)*. Что и требовалось доказать.

Теперь осталось понять что код в начале ответа разлагает исходный определитель по первой строке и получает уравнение *ax + by + c(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>) + d = 0*, где *a*, *b*, *c*, *d* - соответствующие миноры.

У нас есть способ по трём точкам строить уравнение окружности. Если в этом уравнении *c = 0*, исходные точки лежат на одной прямой, решения нет. Если *c ≠ 0*, то из уравнения можно извлечь центр окружности и радиус:

*r = √(a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> - 4cd) / (2c)*

*x<sub>c</sub> = -a / (2c)*

*y<sub>c</sub> = -b / (2c)*

Прелесть этого решения в его численной устойчивости. До момента вычисления последних трёх выражений, использовались только сложение, вычитание и умножение. Проверка вырожденности тройки точек встроена в само уравнение.